# Unity - Blending 3D object with flat picture in the background

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 3d-model

I am struggling with [blending 3D models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_modeling) with a flat background in [Unity](https://unity.com/). What I want to achieve is a desktop app that allows users to import a photo of some room (for example living room) and then use 3D models to "upgrade" the room. Currently, my effects are miserable, it looks awful.

My current approach: after the user imports the photo,
it is displayed on fullscreen canvas with the "screen space - camera" setting. Underneath the camera, I represent a plane, so the user can adjust it with the floor on the picture.
By sliders users can change manually camera angle (X-axis), camera height over the plane, plane size, and plane Y-axis rotation. Later,
when the above parameters are set, users can instantiate different furniture on the surface of the plane, drag it over the surface, etc. I thought that it should be easy to use and accurate, but the effects are unsightly and inaccurate.

Am I missing something? Maybe someone here has experience with such an app?

[imgur picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRzEI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get accurate in the sizing and merging with a 2D background, your best bet would be to delve into Vuforia AR kit for Unity3D, essentially allowing Augmented Reality. With that particular plugin/framework the user can take their camera, and actually place the object, your object, pan it, rotate it, and flip it, and it'll correspond to the screen. You would then have the ability to snap the picture and the dimensions and depth will be actualised.

Flat Background, but depth from phone camera will work work well with your app. This would work for iOS, Android, and a few platforms, I haven't ventured into Windows too much though. Sorry if this isn't helpful.